Understanding a Dynamical System
In my research, I have come across a dynamical system that I’m struggling to understand. I don’t study Dynamical systems, and this is all new to me! I’d love some help understanding the dynamics / get any recommendations on useful results and resources.
The Dynamical System
Let $U,V,W$ be Hilbert spaces (possibly infinitely dimensional), and let $f:U \rightarrow W$ and $g: V \rightarrow W$ be $C^2$ maps. Using $f,g$, define a map $\phi: U \oplus V \rightarrow W$ by $\phi(x,y) = g(y) - f(x)$. I’m interested in trajectories $z(t)$ on $U \oplus V$ satisfying
$$\dot{z}(t) = -(D_{z(t)}\phi)^* \phi (z(t))$$
where $(D_{z(t)} \phi)^* $ denotes the linear adjoint of the derivative $D_{z(t)} \phi: U \oplus V \rightarrow W$. If we write $z(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix}$, we can write these dynamics more explicitly as
$$\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}(t) \\ \dot{y}(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} (D_{x(t)}f)^*(g(y(t)) - f(x(t))) \\ -(D_{y(t)}g)^* (g(y(t)) - f(x(t))) \end{pmatrix} $$
This is an autonomous first order nonlinear dynamical system that kind of looks like gradient descent in a way. I’d like to understand global stability and limiting behavior $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}z(t)$ as we vary the starting point $z_0 := z(0)$. While I’d like to keep the generality of having infinite dimensional $U,V,W$, I’d settle for the finite dimensional case.
Ideas and Partial Results
First of all, I see two different kinds of critical points. A point $z = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is a critical point if either

$f(x) = g(y)$, or
$g(y) - f(x)$ is in the Kernels of both $(D_{x}f)^*$ and $(D_{y}g)^*$.

It seems to me like the collection of critical points of the first kind should be asymptotically stable. For example, if we instantiate $f$ and $g$ as linear maps, it is fairly easy to show using standard linear ODE theory that for every starting point $z_0$, the trajectory $z(t)$ converges to a critical point of the first kind. One key attribute of the linear system is that every critical point of the second kind is also a critical point of the first kind. So if we assume there are no critical points of the second kind, do we get convergence like this?
Second, consider the quantity $\Delta(t) := g(y(t)) - f(x(t))$. With a little work, you can check that
$$\frac{d}{dt} ||\Delta(t)||^2 = - 2\bigg \langle \Delta(t), (D_{x(t)} f) (D_{x(t)} f)^* \Delta(t) \bigg \rangle + \bigg \langle \Delta(t), (D_{y(t)} g) (D_{y(t)} g)^* \Delta(t)\bigg \rangle$$
This quantity is non-positive, and is zero exactly at critical points. This is an energy function for solutions, but that’s not enough to show any kind of convergence. Is there some Lyapunov/LaSalle style theorem that would help give convergence?
Using the local theory around critical points by looking at the spectrum of the quasi-linear system seems promising.
Setting $F:U \oplus V \rightarrow U \oplus V$ to be $F(z) = -(D_z \phi)^* \phi(z)$, we’d want to look at the spectrum of the linear operator $D_{z_0}F$, where $z_0$ is a critical point of $\phi$. The derivative
$$D_{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}} F \begin{pmatrix}{h \\ k} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \big (D^2_x f (h, \cdot) \big )^* [g(y) - f(x)] + (D_x f)^* [D_y g(k) - D_x f(h)] \\ -\big (D^2_y g (\cdot,k) \big )^* [g(y) - f(x)] - (D_y g)^* [D_y g(k) - D_x f(h)] \end{pmatrix}$$
Looking at the sums in each component, we see that one term drops out exactly at each kind of critical point. In the case of critical point $z_0$ of the first kind, we see
$$D_{z_0} F = (D_{z_0} \phi)^* \circ (D_{z_0} \phi)$$
This operator is self adjoint and necessarily has a real, non-negative spectrum. If the spectrum was negative, I’d have useful results to use, but not in this case of a non-negative spectrum. How do we handle the zero?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
